# How do I test if a future method was fired?

Tags: apex

My trigger is receiving 0% coverage and I am unable to deploy.

The problem is, if triggered with success, it sends out an email.

The email method is a @future method.

Is there anyway in Apex to test if a method was called or fired?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get number of future calls using syntax `Limits.getDMLStatements();`. In test class probably you can assert like below,

```
Test.startTest();
//Your test code here
Test.stopTest();
System.assertEquals(Limits.getFutureCalls(),1);
System.assertEquals(Limits.getEmailInvocations(),1);
```

Please remember that asynchronous calls from test class will be executed after Test.stopTest();. So make sure to add Test.StopTest() and assert statements after that

Comment: Just an aside, how do I clear code coverage in dev mode?

Comment: Each time when you run test class, previous coverage will be reset and new coverage will be shown

Comment: What is `.getFutureCalls()`, is that a SF method?

Comment: yeah. Check https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_limits.htm#apex_System_Limits_getFutureCalls

Comment: Okay, have been getting this since many hours now `SubscriptionTrigger, Details: Test coverage of selected Apex Trigger is 0%, at least 1% test coverage is required`. I have this trigger which sends emails only if a campaign is selected. But the code coverage remains 0%. Any way to bypass this? My code is already covering the case, yet it's 0%

Comment: You cannot bypass code coverage requirement for production if you are using changeset. Try to get coverage.

Comment: I tried everything for getting the coverage for the Trigger to be 1%. What is the bare minimum to make it happen. Of course the trigger works but this code coverage issue is stupid.

Comment: You can raise a ticket with salesforce if you feel that it is a genuine issue from Salesforce side.

Comment: Fixed it by covering the code with a better test.